# OpenGL (v >=3) application on remote machine

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, ssh

Is there a way to start an application with OpenGL >= 3 on a remote machine?
Local and remote machine run on Linux.

More precisely, I have the following problem:

I have an application that uses Qt for GUI stuff and OpenGL for 3D rendering.
I want to start this application on several remote machines because the program does some very time consuming computation.

Thus, I created a version of my program that does not raise a window. I use QGuiApplication, QOffscreenSurface, and a framebuffer object as rendertarget.

BUT: When I start the application on a remote machine (ssh -Y remotemachine01 myapp) I only have OpenGL version 2.1.2. When I start the application locally (on the same machine, I have opengl 4.4). I suppose the X forwarding is the problem.

So I need a way to avoid X forwarding.

Comment: I recently realized that, starting an OpenGL-application via ssh executes the OpenGL (i.e. GPU) commands on my local machine. The problem is as follows:

I am in front of machine A. I want to use n machines B_1..._B_n to do some very computationally intensive things on GPU and CPU. The consequence is that the GPU commands of machines B_1...B_n are all executed on machine A. That means, i cannot use the GPU's of B_1...B_n.

Am I wrong, or is there a way to overcome that problem?

I'm currently considering to use Mesa software rendering, but im not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there's no clean solution, sorry.

GLX (the OpenGL extension to X11 which does the forwarding stuff) is only specified up to OpenGL-2.1, hence your inability to forward a OpenGL-3 context. This is actually a ridiculous situation, because the "OpenGL-3 way" is much better suited for indirected rendering, than old fashioned OpenGL-2.1 and earlier. Khronos really needs to get their act together and specify GLX-3.

Your best bet would be either to fall back to a software renderer on the remote side and some form of X compression. Or use Xpra backed by on GPU X11 server; however that only works for only a single user at a time.

In the not too far future the upcomming Linux graphics driver models will allow for remote GPU rendering execution by multiple users sharing graphics resources. But we're not there yet.

Comment: I just tried Xpra. Unfortunately it does not work with Ubuntu 12. I will report if it works after upgrading the linux distro.

Comment: @dmohr: Note that it doesn't suffice to just start Xpra. You have to use the `--xvfb` option set to `/usr/bin/X` so that the regular X server on the GPU is used. Most likely you'll have to configure that to start without attached input devices to work.

Comment: Use virtualgl with xpra, see: https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Usage/OpenGL